# How to show content to staff user only using React and DRF

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a  blog create view, where admin or staff user can only create blog, it is restricted from normal user and it is working fine.

**Goal:** Now I want to display the create blog button on the website to admin or staff user only if they logged in from their account.

I have user detail view that is calling on the very beginning of site loading, How can I check if the user is admin or staff user or normal user in response?

I am using React in frontend with redux.

What I have done so far

```
path('user/', UserDetailsView.as_view(), name='rest_user_details'),

class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_queryset(self):

        return get_user_model().objects.none()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to overwrite your `UserDetailsSerializer` and added a field like `is_admin_user`.

We are going to use [`serializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) from Django-Restframework serializers.

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_admin_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('is_admin_user',) // And all other necessary fields

    def get_is_admin_user(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff # this will return true for self.is_staff user
```

Our main goal is to pass some information to frontend about user role, so that from this information we can decide whether to show create blog button or not.